# How can I bound the `IntoIter` type for `<&Self as IntoIterator>`?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I have a trait for which I want to require that implementing types are iterable by borrow. I have managed to do this using a `for<'x>` higher-ranked trait bound (HRTB) on `&'x Self`.

However, I also want to require that the `IntoIter` associated type implements `ExactSizeIterator`, but every way I try to describe this in the type system causes compilation issues which seem to stem from the use of the HRTB (which I am not fully confident I'm using correctly).

Here is the (simplified) code:

```
struct Thing<'thing>(&'thing ());

trait Trait<'thing>
    where
        for<'x> &'x Self: IntoIterator<Item = &'x Thing<'thing>>,
        // Compiles fine until uncommenting this line:
        //for<'x> <&'x Self as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: ExactSizeIterator
{ }

struct Bucket<'things> {
    things: Vec<Thing<'things>>,
}

struct BucketRef<'a, 'things: 'a> {
    bucket: &'a Bucket<'things>,
}

impl<'x, 'a, 'things: 'a> IntoIterator for &'x BucketRef<'a, 'things> {
    type Item = &'x Thing<'things>;
    type IntoIter = std::slice::Iter<'x, Thing<'things>>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.bucket.things.iter()
    }
}

impl<'a, 'things: 'a> Trait<'things> for BucketRef<'a, 'things> { }

fn foo<'a, 'things>(anchor: &BucketRef<'a, 'things>) {
    println!("{}", ExactSizeIterator::len(&anchor.into_iter()));
}
```

As written this compiles fine, but when I try to further restrict the bounds on `Trait` via the commented line, I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'x> <&'x anchor::BucketRef<'a, 'things> as std::iter::IntoIterator>::IntoIter: std::iter::ExactSizeIterator` is not satisfied
```

It seems to my not-a-compiler-writer mind that given `rustc` appears able to determine inside the function `foo` that all instances of `&BucketRef` are `ExactSizeIterator`s, that it should be able to do similarly for the trait bound, but this is not borne out in reality.

Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work and if there is a better way to express either the bound itself or the intent behind the bound?

```
active toolchain
----------------
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.43.0 (4fb7144ed 2020-04-20)
```

Comment: I think the compiler is just not smart enough yet. Chalk (when integrated) may be able to handle it. Not sure if there is a workaround.

Comment: I suspect it may be because `Iter`'s lifetime parameter is early-bound and therefore part of its type, such that `Iter<'a, T>` is *a different type* to `Iter<'b, T>`, whereas the lifetime in the HRTB is late-bound and therefore sort of implies existential quantification: it means "for *any* lifetime `'x`...", and (as @trentcl says) the compiler is not smart enough to be certain that `ExactSizeIterator` will be implemented on all the particular `Iter<'x, _>` types for whatever lifetimes `'x` that one's references to `BucketRef` might happen to have.

Comment: Perhaps the following quote from the [nomicon chapter on variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance) is relevant: "*Invoking contravariance involves higher-order programming with function pointers that take references with specific lifetimes (as opposed to the usual "any lifetime", which gets into higher rank lifetimes, which work independently of subtyping).*"—if the lifetime `'x` in the HRTB "works independently of subtyping", then that would explain why it cannot be reconciled with the lifetime parameter on `Iter`.

Comment: @eggyal I appreciate your apparently rather prolonged interest in the outcome of this question! I'm a bit outside the headspace at the moment and at the best of times I never knew much about the deeper type theory of Rust, so I can't really give an engaged response, sorry. 
Would it be possible to get a dumbed-down version of your last two comments? In particular, I'm not clear on the meaning of phrase "early/late-bound" and I don't really understand the concept of variance.

Answer (score 2):

this maybe related to this compiler bug and will be fixed soon: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56556

https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/85499

workarounds:
https://github.com/Lucretiel/joinery/blob/master/src/join.rs#L174-L188